# Aws cli upload certified ssl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, aws-cli

I have to upload the certificate server via aws cli.
The CA gave me only 2 files. I do not own the RSA.

To do this, enter this command in the shell:
aws iam upload-server-certified --server-certified-name certificate_object_name --certificate-body file: // public_key_certificate_file --private-key files: //privatekey.pem --certificate-chain file: // certificate_chain_file

Can anyone describe all parameters ??

Answer (score 1):

- Public key: This is the certificate that is presented to clients to verify that your server is who it claims to be. It is tied to your site (www.example.com) or to multiple sites (www.example.com, foo.example.com, bar.example.com) using [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), or to an entire domain (*.example.com) if it is a [wildcard certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate).
- Private key: This is the secret portion of your asymmetric keypair. This is to be carefully protected with filesystem permissions and never to be shared. It normally starts with:

  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
- Certificate chain: This has to do with the [Chain of trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust). In order to permit many certificate authorities to issue certificates, a root CA signs the certificates of intermediate CAs with their private key to indicate that those CAs can be trusted. Your certificate issuer will provide the intermediate certificates. It usually comes bundled with your issued certificate. If not, you can usually find it on the issuer's web site.